# Move last 100 items from one folder to another folder with the same folder name

Tags: linux, files, mv

Every folder here got about 1000 items, and I wish to "move" the last 100 items to another directory by creating the same folder name and store it.

Example:

```
/original/folder1/
/original/folder2/
       ...
/original/folder50/
```

Ibwish to move the last 100 items from every folder above to destination below which is not created at the very beginning.

```
/dest/folder1/
/dest/folder2/
      ....
/dest/folder50/
```

Comment: by what criteria is **last** defined? Files are placed in folder in arbitrary order

Comment: [How to get the last N files in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181069) should get you started...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the last 100 files in every single folder

Comment: "Last" implies an ordering. What ordering are you using? Date? Name? Size? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible solution. But it will work. Pay attention to the paths and what cut field to set based on your directory structure.

```
for i in `find original/ -type d | grep -v 'original/$'`;
  do foldernames=`echo $i | cut -d "/" -f 3-`; 
  mkdir -p dest/$foldernames ; 
  ls $i | tail -n 100 | xargs -i -t mv $i/{} dest/$foldernames ; 
done
```

Comment: You're right, it's horrible. [Don't loop over `find`'s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and quote your vars...